# If $T^*T=T^2$, then prove the operator $T$ is self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators

> Let V be an n-dimensional inner product space over C and T ∈ L(V ). Suppose that
> $T^2 = T^∗T$. Prove that T is self-adjoint.

My idea is since $T^*T$ is positive, then all the eigenvalues of it should be nonnegative. Also, since $T^2=T^*T$, then this is also true for $T^2$. Then suppose $T$ has a eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $T^2$ should have eigenvalue $\lambda^2\geq0$. This forces all the eigenvalues for $T$ must be real, since it's impossible to have $(a+bi)^2\geq0$ with $b\neq 0$. Thus, now I think can prove some other things to prove $T$ is self-adjoint.

1. If $T$ is normal, then $T$ is self-adjoint
2. By Schur theorem, there exists an orthonormal basis such that $T$ is upper triangular. If I can prove all the entries above the diagonal of $M(T)$ are zero, then $T$ is self-adjoint

However, unfortunately, I can prove none of them. Also, I was able to solve a similar problem

> If $TT^*=T^2$ then $T$ is self-adjoint

This question enable me to say that if $Tv=0$ then $T^*v=0$ by using norm $$ \|T^*v\|^2=\langle T^*v,T^*v\rangle=\langle TT^*v,v\rangle=\langle T^2v,v\rangle=0$$

And by $\dim$ null $T$ = $\dim$ null $T^*$, I can prove null $T$ = null $T^*$ which gives $T$ is normal, but this seems not useful in this problem, or probably I missed something

Anyway, any help is appreciated. Thank!

Comment: try using cauchy-schwarz

Comment: $\langle T^*Tv,v\rangle =\|Tv\|^2$ ( since $T^*T$ is positive, so no need for absolute value). Then $\langle T^2v,v\rangle =\langle Tv,T^*v\rangle \leq \|Tv\|\|T^*v\|$  Since $T^*T=T^2$, this gives $\|Tv\|^2 \leq \|Tv\| \|T^*v\| $. Thus if $T^*v=0$, then this forces $Tv =0 $ Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were able to prove

$$\tag1TT^*=T^2\ \implies\ T=T^*$$

and you have $T^*T=T^2$, then taking adjoints you have $T^*T=(T^*)^2$. Letting $S=T^*$, this is $$ SS^*=S^2.$$ Now you know by $(1)$ that $S=S^*$, so $T=T^*$.

---

Using more explicitly that you are in a finite-dimensional setting, here is another argument. You have
$$
(T-T^*)^2=T^2+T^{*2}-T^*T-TT^*=T^*T-TT^*. 
$$
Multiplying by $i$ and taking the trace,
$$
\operatorname{Tr}\big[[i(T-T^*)]^2\big]=0
$$
So the operator $i(T-T^*)$ is selfadjoint and its square is zero; so it is zero. Then $T-T^*=0$.

Comment: Thanks! The (1) is exactly what I was trying to do but I ended up confusing myself...

Comment: Also, could you please explain why multiplying by $i$? And $i(T-T^*)^2=iT^*T-iTT^*$, and if I take the adjoint of it, the result will be $-iT^*T+iTT^*$, so is this really self-adjoint?

Comment: No, its $i(T-T^*)$ that is selfadjoint. Its square is $TT^*-T^*T$.

Comment: So you mean that $i(T-T^*)$ is self-adjoint, so it only has real eigenvalues $\lambda$, then the square of it is $[i(T-T^*)]^2$ which has eigenvalues $\lambda^2$. Then since the trace of its square is zero, $\sum \lambda^2=0$, and hence this implies all $\lambda$ is zero, which gives $i(T-T^*)$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis with all eigenvalues are zero. Thus $i(T-T^*)=0\implies T=T^*$. This is the right interpretation?

Comment: Yep. Exactly that.